# ¿Cómo obtener la foto de perfil de Facebook con Graph-SDK 5.5 PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Estoy realizando un inicio de sesión a *Facebook* y necesito obtener la imagen de perfil pero en un tamaño más grande. Con este código obtengo su foto de perfil en tamaño *50px*50px* pero necesito una foto mas grande.

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,email,picture,first_name,last_name', $accessToken);
$me = $response->getGraphUser();
$_SESSION['facebook'] = (string) $accessToken;
$_SESSION['nombre'] = $me->getFirstName();
$_SESSION['apellido'] = $me->getLastName();
$_SESSION['idFacebook'] = $me->getId();
$_SESSION['email'] = $me->getEmail();
$_SESSION['foto'] = $me->getPicture()->getUrl();
```

Comment: La API tiene un parámetro `type` para las fotos, donde puedes poner: small, normal, large, square. Si le pasas a la llamada algo como `type=large` te dará la foto en grande. O si quieres un ancho y largo específico la API tiene también `width` y `height` puedes hacer una llamada usando ambos. Exactamente cómo se pasan los parámetros no sé decirte porque no uso la API de FB, pero si existen es para usarlos. No creo que sea difícil, prueba a pasar parámetros sea con type o con width-height

Comment: Gracias :D usé el picture.width(400).height(400)

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al momento de hacer la solicitud por medio de get a Facebook, le puedes pasar los parámetros de ancho y alto de la imagen de esta manera:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,email,picture.width(400).height(400),first_name,last_name', $accessToken);
```

Siendo los números entre paréntesis las dimensiones en píxeles:

> picture.width(300).height(300)

Comment: Si sirvió, muchas gracias :D

Comment: @StivenTriana También puedes votar la respuesta como positiva, flecha gris indicando hacia arriba, a la izquierda.